# Compare a GIT bare repo and bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

How can I make sure that my bare repo and my bitbucket repo are identical?

First thing I did was to look at the logs, but that may be not enough right?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the entire repo, including all history, not just the respective HEADs?

Comment: good point. I may need that indeed.

Comment: There is always a few "far too smart" trolls that bother to vote down a question that received a great answer. They should instead Vote UP the great answer, that is even if they find my question too stupid to be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- create a local repository
- add a remote for your bare repository
- add a remote for your bitbucket repository
- fetch from both repositories.
- verify that the corresponding branches point to the same commits

I would probably do it like this:

```
git init
git remote add bare $bareuri
git remote add bitb $bitbucketuri
git fetch --all
gitk --all
```

I would expect `bare/master` point to the same commit as `bitb/master`, etc.