# Is a Bitbucket repository "--bare" or not?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bare

I just created a Bitbucket account and already made a few commits to the Bitbucket server. I also invited my team to check the Bitbucket repo for changes.

But, after a while, I found an article saying that every shared repo should be a *--bare* one.

Is my Bitbucket repo, that I've created via the Bitbucket web interface are *--bare* one? Or should I create another *--bare* directory on my machine?

Is this necessary to do what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394011/3763032) to handle two remote repos?

Comment: BitBucket is a repository hosting service and they have no reason to use repositories with attached working copies. No working copy also saves them lots of space.

Comment: @knittl did you mean, I can't work on any big project with my teammates?

Comment: No, I meant it's only in the best interest of BitBucket to use bare repositories on their servers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, you can assume that your bitbucket-repository is a bare-repository. **By design**.

Because all repositories that are hosted remote and are only to push-to should be bare. There's no reason to assume something different.

If you are unsure, [follow your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394011/3763032) and compare. But you don't need another git repository if you are happy with bitbucket as a host.

Comment: thank you very much sir :) yeah, this is answered my doubtness. So, I just need to continue my project rather than confused to create another git --bare repository :D

Answer (score 5):

In Bitbucket's command line instructions to clone a repo, the remote repo named has the `.git` extension. From the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server),

> By convention, bare repository directories end in `.git`